# Working of a Solar Cell

Tags: solar-cell

In a solar cell the N-type is made thin so that the light can pass through it and reach the depletion region of the junction. How and why is the light able to pass the N-type region and why doesn't it gets absorbed there?

Answer (score 3):

You answered the question yourself:

> the N-type is made thin so that the light can pass through it

The N-type layer is only a few hundred nm thick, the P-type layer could be a few hundred μm thick so there's way more depth (~three orders of magnitude!) for the photon to be absorbed in.